# Caption centered and at the bottom of a background

Tags: css, reactjs, image, center, caption

I'm a React beginnerCan you explain me how to place a .herogroup (composed by h1, p and a button) in the middle and 20px far away from the bottom of a background (belonging to .Hero)?

```
<div>
 <div className="Hero">
   <div className="HeroGroup">
    <h1>ABC</h1>
    <p>ABC</p>
    <Link to="ABC">ABC</Link>
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.Hero {
height: 1920px;
background-image: url('../images/abc.jpg');
background-size: cover;}

.HeroGroup{
max-width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 150px 50px;
text-align: center;}
```

Comment: @editors, this is a react code so please no automatic snippet transformation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used css `flex`. Which is more convenient to achieve your case than using position absolute.

```css
.Hero {
    height: 1920px;
    background-image: url('../images/abc.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.HeroGroup{
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  display: flex;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="Hero">
   <div class="HeroGroup">
    <h1>ABC</h1>
    <p>ABC</p>
    <Link to="ABC">ABC</Link>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: sure, Done it ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your .HeroGroup class do this

```
.HeroGroup {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 150px 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
}
```